# Ruby on rails - cannot load such file -- net/ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-ssh

I've been struggling on this for a few days now..

When I try to call a method in a helper from a view to do ssh, it throws that error.

> "This error occurred while loading the following files: net/ssh"

But when I copy the code into a `test.rb` file and execute it from prompt `ruby test.rb` it connects flawlessly.

What could be the problem ? I tried on another computer and same result.

Thank you very much this is like the last step before I can complete my project!

Regards,

`application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(value)
    unless value.nil?
      @title = "#{value} | Eucc"      
    end
  end
  def execute
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ssh'
    @hostname = "smtlmon02"
    @username = "gcaille"
    @password = "qaz1234"
    @cmd = "ls -al"
    @cmd2 = "sudo su - -c 'ls;date'"

    ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
    res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
    res2 = ssh.exec!(@cmd2)

    ssh.close
    File.open("output.txt", 'w') {|file| file.write(res2)}
  end
end
```

Comment: have you installed net-ssh gem?

Comment: Yes in did gem install net-ssh. Like I said, if I run this script from command prompt it is working.

Comment: I changed require 'net/ssh' for require 'net-ssh' and same results:
cannot load such file -- net-ssh

and I did again :
C:\Users\guillaume.caille>gem install net-ssh
Successfully installed net-ssh-2.8.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.8.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.8.0...

Comment: It's added to you gemfile? Just wondering since you showed us installing it to the box.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace of the error? Also helper is not the place for this method. You should probably move it to model or some utility

Comment: It is not in the file named "gemfile" in the root of my project.

Do I have to add it this way ?

gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.8.0'

Comment: Well the full stacktrace is 10 000 char too long to be posted here

Comment: Thank you !! I added this line into my gemfile and did bundle install. it added net-ssh and it is now working.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just need to add it to Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```

and run bundle install after that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart your IDE as well. I had this problem with Net::SFTP and Sergey Moiseev's solution worked great, but I had to restart my IDE after the bundle install.