# Possible issues with the rake rails:update:bin command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I have had this issue and I have not been able to solve it. I have posted two questions prior to this. The problem is with the rails server (WEBrick). It was running fine in development. I installed a simple jquery-ui gem and ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` and the server stopped working. The error is given below.

```
Server Error    
    warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
    Error: Command '-b' not recognized
    Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

After doing further investigation, I realized that the way to fix this is updating bin, so I ran the command, `rake rails:update:bin`. This also gave me an error. The snippet of the error is given below.

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh

/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I figured that if I could fix the rake command issue, I could potentially run the command and fix the server problem. I tried looking for solution on the web, however, they were focused towards MySQL database. I run sqlite3 version 1.3.9 in development. I have looked for potential reasons why `rake rails:update:bin` command would fail and give me that error but I haven't found a clear answer. I have never changed any of the code in the `config/bin` directory. Everything looks normal.

I have been trying to debug the this problem for the past two days. I have had no luck. I have tried to un-install gems such as spring and PostgreSQL and installed them again to see if they causing any problems. Not the problem. I have read almost every suggestion on the web. None of them really have the same issue as mine. If anyone can help me figure this problem out, It would be a great deal of help. Any documentation, posts or anything that can help me solve the problem would be highly appreciated. I hope I made myself clear and included all the relevant information, I tried to keep it concise. If any additional detail is needed, please do let me know. Again, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

here is very similar post.
[Ruby on rails - cannot load such file -- net/ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481691/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-net-ssh)

Only you need is add this to your Gemfile and install.

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```

It worked for me.